# Android Chornometer stopwatch tick at .25 speed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, chronometer

I am currently using a stopwatch timer in a sports app on Android Studio and have implemented it using a Chronometer. I'm wondering if its possible to make the Chronometer tick/increment at 0.25 speed?

Comment: I don't think it is possible using the `Chronometer` API.